# Using k8s, a service and deployment were created, but the pod cannot be accessed using the IP of the service

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, web

I am a k8s beginner，I am practicing using k8s to run a springboot application，I used kubeadm to install a single node k8s。I confirmed that k8s has been installed，The following is the version information

```
[root@devops1722021165 k8s]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.3", GitCommit:"06ad960bfd03b39c8310aaf92d1e7c12ce618213", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-11T18:14:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.17", GitCommit:"f3abc15296f3a3f54e4ee42e830c61047b13895f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:13:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
[root@devops1722021165 k8s]# kubectl get nodes
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
devops1722021165   Ready    master   23d   v1.17.3
```

I have the simplest springboot application

```
/**
 * @author zhengtao on 2023/12/2
 */
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

I've made him a image and uploaded to dockerhub，I wrote a docker-study-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-study-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-study-deployment
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-study-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: docker-study
        image: wzgl998877/docker-study
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and I executed kubectl apply -f docker-study-deployment.yaml command
then I worte a docker-study-svc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: docker-study-svc

spec:
  selector:
    app: docker-study-deployment

  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
```

and I executed kubectl apply -f docker-study-svc.yaml command
docker-study-deployment and docker-study-svc is running

But when I execute curl [http://10.97.154.229:30577/hello，it's](http://10.97.154.229:30577/hello%EF%BC%8Cit%27s) not responding。and when I go inside the pod，execute curl http://10.97.154.229:8080/hello, response curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.97.154.229 port 8080: Connection refused.
I hope you can help me solve this problem，thank you！！！

I am a k8s beginner，I am practicing using k8s to run a springboot application，I used kubeadm to install a single node k8s。I confirmed that k8s has been installed，The following is the version information

```
[root@devops1722021165 k8s]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.3", GitCommit:"06ad960bfd03b39c8310aaf92d1e7c12ce618213", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-11T18:14:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.17", GitCommit:"f3abc15296f3a3f54e4ee42e830c61047b13895f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:13:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
[root@devops1722021165 k8s]# kubectl get nodes
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
devops1722021165   Ready    master   23d   v1.17.3
```

I have the simplest springboot application

```
/**
 * @author zhengtao on 2023/12/2
 */
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

I've made him a image and uploaded to dockerhub，I wrote a docker-study-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-study-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-study-deployment
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-study-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: docker-study
        image: wzgl998877/docker-study
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and I executed kubectl apply -f docker-study-deployment.yaml command
then I worte a docker-study-svc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: docker-study-svc

spec:
  selector:
    app: docker-study-deployment

  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
```

and I executed kubectl apply -f docker-study-svc.yaml command
docker-study-deployment and docker-study-svc is running

```
[root@devops1722021165 k8s]# kubectl describe svc docker-study-svc
Name:                     docker-study-svc
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"docker-study-svc","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port"...
Selector:                 app=docker-study-deployment
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.97.154.229
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30577/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.33:8080,10.244.0.34:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

But when I execute curl [http://10.97.154.229:30577/hello，it's](http://10.97.154.229:30577/hello%EF%BC%8Cit%27s) not responding。and when I go inside the pod，execute curl http://10.97.154.229:8080/hello, response curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.97.154.229 port 8080: Connection refused.
I hope you can help me solve this problem，thank you！！！

Comment: In the pod, you should use `localhost:8080` for your tests.

Comment: i already tried and have a Correct response
root@docker-study-deployment-7df4688d95-jrqzz:/java# curl http://localhost:8080/hello
hello worldroot@docker-study-deployment-7df4688d95-jrqzz:/java#

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.